# Why doesnt my ball appear on screen when I run this code?

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I run this program everything but the ball appears and works. Before I tried to program the balls movement it appeared on the screen so I know it has something to do with that

I have tried tracing back to what made the ball disappear but I can't find it

```
import pygame
from gameObject import GameObject

pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('FNT', 80)

pygame.init()

class Player(GameObject):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_path, speed):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, image_path)

        self.speed = speed 

    def move(self, direction, max_height):
        if (self.y >= max_height - self.height and direction > 0) or (self.y <= 0 and direction < 0):
            return

        self.y += (direction * self.speed)

class Ball(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_path, speed):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, image_path)
        self.speed = speed

    
    def move(self, max_height, dx, dy):
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.speed = abs(self.speed)
        elif (self.y >= max_height - self.height and dy > 0) or (self.y <= 0 and dy < 0):
            self.y = -self.y
        
        self.y += (dx * self.speed)
        self.x += (dy * self.speed)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 800
        self.white_color = (255, 255, 255)


        self.game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.background = GameObject(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 'assets/background.png')

        self.level = 1.0

        self.reset_map()

       

    def reset_map(self):
        self.player1 = Player(-200, 300, 500, 175, 'assets/player.png', 10) 
        self.player2 = Player(500, 300, 500, 175, 'assets/player.png', 10 )
        self.ball = Ball(400, 400, 40, 40, 'assets/ball.png', 3)
       # self.ball.speed = 3

      #  if self.level >= 9:
     #       self.ball.speed = 15
      #  elif self.level >= 7:
       #     self.ball.speed = 10
       # elif self.level >= 3:
      #      self.ball.speed = 5
        
         
        
        
    def draw_objects(self):
        self.game_window.fill(self.white_color) 

        self.game_window.blit(self.background.image, (self.background.x, self.background.y))
        self.game_window.blit(self.player1.image, (self.player1.x, self.player1.y))
        self.game_window.blit(self.player2.image, (self.player2.x, self.player2.y))
        self.game_window.blit(self.ball.image, (self.ball.x, self.ball.y))

        pygame.display.update()
        
    def move_objects(self, player1_direction, player2_direction, dx, dy):  
        self.player1.move(player1_direction, self.height)
        self.player2.move(player2_direction, self.height)
        self.ball.move(dx, dy, self.height)
    
    def check_if_collided(self):
        if self.detect_collision(self.player1, self.ball):
            return True
        if self.detect_collision(self.player2, self.ball):
            return True
                
    def detect_score(self, ball):
        if ball.x >= 800 - self.width:
            True
        elif ball.x <= 0 - self.width:          
            True
        else:
            False

    def bounce(self, ball, dy, dx):
        if ball.y >= 800 - self.height:
            dy *= -1
            self.level += 1
        elif ball.y <= 0 - self.height:
            dx *= -1
            self.level += 1


    def detect_collision(self, object_1, object_2):
        if object_1.y < (object_2.y + object_2.height) and (object_1.y + object_1.height) > object_2.y and object_1.x < (object_2.x + object_2.width) and (object_1.x + object_1.width) > object_2.x:
            return True
        return False

    def run_game_loop(self):
        player1_direction = 0
        player2_direction = 0
        dx = .1
        dy = -.1
       

        gameRunning = True
        while gameRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameRunning = False
                if gameRunning == False:
                    pygame.quit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player2_direction = -1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        player2_direction = 1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        player1_direction = -1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        player1_direction = 1

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        player2_direction = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        player1_direction = 0
                
                   

            self.draw_objects()

            self.move_objects(player1_direction, player2_direction, dx, dy)  
  
            if self.check_if_collided():
                self.bounce()
            
            if self.detect_score(self.ball):
                self.reset_map()

            self.clock.tick(60)
   

game = Game()

game.run_game_loop()

quit()
```

Game Object:

```
import pygame 

class GameObject:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_path):
        background = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (width, height))

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

Comment: I suggest printing the x and y coordinates of the ball in your `while gameRunning` loop. Then you can scope the problem down to either a (pygame) drawing issue or a calculation issue

Comment: If anything, `dx` and `dy` are not globals, not properties, and are not returned by function calls. Ergo, `bounce` does nothing except for incrementing Game.level, which currently also does nothing. Most likely, your ball just falls through the "floor". I am also nearly sure the bounce logic is weird/wrong overall, as it should be flipping the `y` direction in both cases, and by not normalizing dx^2 + dy^2 you get Source Engine-like behavior where going at an angle is strictly faster than just up/down or left/right.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has no concept of in-out parameters. If you change the parameter variable in a function, it does not affect the variable you passed to the function. See toe following simple example:

```py
def foo(x):
    x += 1
    print(f'x in foo is {x}')

x = 2
foo(x)
print(f'x is {x}')
```

output:

> ```
> x in foo is 3
> x is 2
> ```

If you want to change the a value in a function you have to return the new value from the function. e.g.:

```py
def foo(x):
    x += 1
    print(f'x in foo is {x}')
    return x

x = 2
x = foo(x)
print(f'x is {x}')
```

output:

> ```
> x in foo is 3
> x is 3
> ```

Consider that, for instance, in `Game.bounce`.